# Яндекс карты API. Маршрутизация. Название точки

Tags: яндекс-карты, яндекс-карта-api

Параметры маршрута:

```
    routePanelControl.routePanel.state.set({

        // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
        fromEnabled: false,
        // Адрес или координаты пункта отправления.
        from: [storeLat,storeLng],
        // Выключим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
        toEnabled: false,
        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
        to: toPoint,

    });
```

В from я ввожу координаты. На карте появляется название точки маршрута (например, Москва, ул. Третьяковская) - его яндекс сам выводит. Можно ли как-то задать это название самостоятельно?

Comment: А зачем вам панель маршрутизации, если точки задаёте жёстко сами? Используйте мультироутер, а адреса напишите в кастомном поле, если надо.

Comment: У меня по-разному. Первая точка задается. Вторая - либо пользователем, либо кодом. В том случае, когда адрес вводится не вручную, хотелось задать название точки. Но спасибо за наводку. Уберу панель. Поле ввода второй точки будет отдельно от карты. Для построения маршрута использую маршрутизатор